# R: How to mix a series of variables and Greek symbols in a string

Tags: r, plotmath

Suppose x and y are variables. I am trying to create a graph title that has a Latex equivalent of  `$\sigma_v =$ 3 $\rho =$ 5`,  where the values 3 and 5 come from R variables.

Here is the closest I have been able to come (modeled after an example in ?plotmath):

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 3
z <- 5
plot(x,x)
mtext(substitute(list(sigma[v],rho) == group("(",list(a,b),")"),list(a=y,b=z)))
```

Is it possible to have a sequence of "variable = number" strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LaTex expression didn't have a comma separating the two pairs but it appears you did want one in there so see if this is a good solution:

```
mtext(substitute(sigma[v] == a *","~ rho == b, list(a=y,b=z)))
```

To comment on the notion of "concatenating expressions" raised by mcd: Valid (invisible) "concatenators" are `~` and `*` and the (visible) infix operators. Spaces are *not* valid separators (and they are ignored). You do not need to quote anything except commas, parentheses not used for visible grouping of uninterpreted sub-expressions, and carets and brackets not used for their side-effects. Sometimes it is handier to quote a long line of text because spaces are easier to type than multiple `*`'s or tilde's to separate non-plotmath-ish words.

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect! I was unable to figure out the syntax for concatenating expressions, now I get it.

Comment: thank you one more time. Your additional remarks about concatenation are very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `bquote()` to do what you said you wanted (LaTeX equivalent). Here is an example:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 3
z <- 5
plot(x,x)
title(main = bquote(sigma[v] == .(y) ~~ rho == .(z)))
```